# How to set JAVA_HOME environment in mac?

Tags: java

If I write the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` the address is not the true address I need.

[image]

I have written this in my `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I `source .bash_profile` and echo again

[image]

the address `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home` is the right address I need.

But if I open a terminal again, it will still echo address `/Users/yuntao_qiu/.sdkman/candidates/java/current`. This address is the wrong address.

So how can I set my `$JAVA_HOME` to be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home`. No need let me the source again and again.

Comment: Check your `~/.bashrc`. Maybe the value of `JAVA_HOME` is being overwritten

Comment: @rdas +1 this is probably the issue